# Why Vector code is slower than standard list one

Tags: haskell

I have read about `Vector` library that uses modern optimization techniques and try to compare its perfomance with lists. The code below generates some sound-like data (which is important to my subject area) and sums the result:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.TimeIt
import Data.List
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

x1 :: Int -> [Double]
x1 n = [1..(fromIntegral n)]

x2 :: Int -> V.Vector Double
x2 n = V.enumFromN 1 n

osc1 f = Prelude.map (\x -> sin(2*pi*x*f/44100.0))
osc2 f = V.map (\x -> sin(2*pi*x*f/44100.0))

sum1 = Data.List.foldl1' (+)
sum2 = V.foldl1' (+)

zip1 = Prelude.zipWith (+)
zip2 = V.zipWith (+)

main = do s <- getArgs
          let n = read (s !! 0) :: Int
          print "Prelude version"
          timeIt $ print $ sum1 $ zip1 (osc1 55.5 (x1 n)) (osc1 110.0 $ x1 n)
          print "Vector version"
          timeIt $ print $ sum2 $ zip2 (osc2 55.5 (x2 n)) (osc2 110.0 $ x2 n)
```

GHC 7.6.3 running on win7 with vector0.10.0.1 and timeit1.0.0.0 gave me these results:

```
c:\coding>test 10000000
"Prelude version"
90.98579564908658
CPU time:   9.92s
"Vector version"
90.98579564908658
CPU time:  11.03s
```

Vector version is a little bit slower even being `Unboxed` and it takes 22.67 seconds for the boxed Vector version. Why does this happen? How should I write this code to get maximum perfomace?

UPD. After adding `-O2` (**) I got more clear to me results. It looks like boxed vectors are harder to fuse.

```
                  List    Vector.Unboxed    Vector
ghc test.hs       9.78    10.94             21.95
ghc test.hs -O2   3.39    1.25              7.57
```

(**) I didn't note because ghc doesn't recompile unchanged files even if command line flags are different and I hadn't actually run `-O2` version before noticed that. Sorry

Comment: How are you compiling? What did you find when profiling your code?

Comment: Hm, I compiled with "ghc test.hs". -O2 changes the results and I should add this...

Comment: Updated. First I compared results with and without `-O2` and they didn't differ much but it was just because it wasn't actually recompiled. Now it is more clear but I still wonder why boxed vectors are slower

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of optimization flags:

**-o0**

```
>test 10000000
"Prelude version"
90.98579564908658
CPU time:   6.66s
"Vector version"
90.98579564908658
CPU time:   8.27s
```

**-o1**

```
>test 10000000
"Prelude version"
90.98579565011536
CPU time:   2.70s
"Vector version"
90.98579565011924
CPU time:   1.62s
```

**-o2**

```
>test 10000000
"Prelude version"
90.98579565011536
CPU time:   2.72s
"Vector version"
90.98579565011924
CPU time:   1.34s
```

From [Haskell tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info):

> **Performance issues**
>
> In case of performance issues, please make sure that you compile your
> code with optimizations enabled. Passing -O2 makes many performance
> issues go away.

*update*

For a quick explanation on why Unboxed is faster [here's one](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial#Boxed_Arrays:_Data.Vector):

> The most flexible type is Data.Vector.Vector, which provides *boxed* arrays: arrays of pointers to Haskell values.
>
> These arrays are suitable for storing complex Haskell types (sum types, or algebraic data types), but a better choice for simple data types is Data.Vector.Unboxed.

For Unboxed:

> Simple, atomic types, and pair types can be stored in a more efficient manner: consecutive memory slots without pointers.

[off] Optimization's slightly changing the result, that's interesting. [/off]

Comment: I was sure that I posted `-O2` results. This is how it looks at my machine: http://pastebin.com/jGzN6NKC . I still have question why are boxed vectors so slow.

Comment: See my edit, it probably has to do with Unboxed requiring less memory manipulation (less pointer arithmetic, lower store and load costs).

Comment: Ok, thanks. can you add "These arrays are suitable for storing complex Haskell types (sum types, or algebraic data types), but a better choice for simple data types is Data.Vector.Unboxed." to your explanation?

Comment: Use -fforce-recomp when changing an optimization flag. There is an old bug that if you change compilation flags, ghc won't recompile the code for you.

(you could also delete .o .hi and .exe files generated by ghc, to be sure you have the right executable)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the `vector` version is forced to actually materialize the vector (allocating memory for it) and working with that much like an implementation using `for` loops and arrays in an imperative setting. In a sense it "does what one would expect" (when having an imperative background at least).

But there's something interesting happening with the version using lists, and this magic is called "stream fusion": The compiler is smart enough to figure out that it is sufficient to keep track of the sum in order to compute the final result. This is done by computing values and adding them up, finally printing out the sum. The actual list is never needed at all, so it's never allocated or traversed.

I did not verify this by looking at the generated Core, so...

Comment: Vector library is claimed to use fusion too

Comment: They use different kinds of fusion. The standard library's lists use foldr/build fusion. Vector uses stream fusion.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling with optimizations enabled, `Vector` is faster.  When optimizations are turned on, the compiler inlines and specializes vector functions, eliminating a lot of function calls and boxed temporary values.

Switching to streams gives you another 1.5× improvement by fusing all the steps of computation into a single loop.  No arrays are built.

```
import Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream as S

x3 :: Int -> S.Stream Double
x3 n = S.enumFromStepN 1 1 n
osc3 f = S.map (\x -> sin(2*pi*x*f/44100.0))
sum3 = S.foldl1' (+)
zip_3 = S.zipWith (+)

main = do s <- getArgs
          let n = read (s !! 0) :: Int
          print "Stream version"
          timeIt $ print $ sum3 $ zip_3 (osc3 55.5 (x3 n)) (osc3 110.0 $ x3 n)
```

Stream fusion on `Vector`s won't fuse the input of `zipWith`, so the vector code doesn't optimize in the same way.

Compiling with `-O2`, the Prelude version is slowest and the `Stream` version is fastest.

```
$ ./Test 10000000
"Prelude version"
90.98579565011536
3.051188s
"Vector version"
90.98579565011924
1.81228s
"Stream version"
90.98579565011907
1.155345s
```

Comment: I got 1.03s using vectors versus 0.97s using streams, improvement doesn't look so significant, what can be the difference between our systems?

Comment: @DmitryGalchinsky Maybe compiler optimizations have changed.  I'm using GHC 7.4.1 and vector-0.10.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with laziness. The example that uses lists can take advantage of lazy evaluation, so it effectively iterates through the range of numbers without ever storing any lists in memory. The example with vectors must actually allocate a vector in memory which takes some extra time.

For situations like this where the list never needs to be stored in memory, lists are probably faster. For situations where you actually do need to store the data in memory, vectors will usually be faster.

Comment: I don't think it's laziness but rather stream fusion at work here. Laziness does not have an impact because all potentially computed values affect the output (and thus are actually needed).